# Opening a file with the default application (with permission enforcement)

Tags: android, permissions

My application has read and write permissions to the download folder. How to call the default application to open a file and give it the right to read the file?
When use this code, the default application opens, but cannot access the file:

```
public void openFile(String fileName)
{
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName);
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(fileName);
    newIntent.setDataAndType(myUri, mimeType);
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);          
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        this.startActivity(newIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No handler for this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Acrobat reader, for example, reports that there is no access to the file.
Only the GoogleFoto app when opened asked permission and successfully opened the picture.

Comment: Use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` to serve up this file. Note that `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` only have meaning for a `Uri` that points to a `ContentProvider` like `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to CommonsWare

**android/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!-- file provider for open attached files-->
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

**android/res/xml/file_provider_paths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
  <files-path name="files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public String openFile(String filePath)
{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (!file.exists())
        return "file not exist";

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filePath);

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    newIntent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                  
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        this.startActivity(newIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No handler for this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return "No handler for this type of file.";
    }
    return "";
}
```